# Categorical meaning of the two definitions of $\pi_n(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I know that the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(X)$ can be defined in two way.

1. Homotopy classes of the continuos maps $(I^n,\partial I^n)\longrightarrow (X,x_0)$.
2. Homotopy classes of the continuos maps $(S^n,s_0)\longrightarrow (X,x_0)$.

These two ways to define the higher homotopy groups are equivalent. We can see this by using the universal proprerty of the quotient topological space. My question is...Is there a categorical meaning of the equivalence of these two definitions?

Comment: I believe that your answer depends on what you mean by *categorical meaning*. Could you add some details?

Comment: Arguably, you could say that the "categorical reason" (but of course it is really a topological reason) is that there is a mapping $q: (I^n, \partial I^n) \to (S^n,s_0)$, the quotient mapping, such that the pullback $q^*: \mathrm{Hom}((S^n, s_0), (X, x_0)) \to \mathrm{Hom}((I^n, \partial I^n), (X,x_0))$ is a natural bijection.

Comment: Maybe I have an idea...I think that defining the homotopy groups as in (1), then we have an isomorphism of group objects $\pi_n\cong \mathbf{Top}(S^n,-)$.

Comment: I think you mean $\pi_n\cong\textbf{hTop}_*(S^n,-)$, where $\textbf{hTop}_*$ is the homotopy category of based topological spaces. In this sense the structure of $\pi_n(X)$ comes from $S^n$ being a *cogroup* object in $\textbf{hTop}_*$.

Comment: The question is too vague. What do you want to know exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a background to this use of either cubes or spheres, but it needs a more general setting which is given in this paper [Modelling and Computing Homotopy Types: $1$](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brouwer-honor.pdf) to appear in Indagationes Math. in 2017.

One distinction between the use of cubes and spheres is that the composition or gluing of cubes is very clear, while the composition for homotopy groups defined by spheres is less direct. In a general setting, this can be seen as **broad** and **narrow** methods, and both are needed in the subject.

This distinction is not easy to see in the use of groups, although the use of various geometric models (cells, simplices, cubes, ...) has been standard in homotopy theory almost since its inception.  The distinction becomes necessary when one moves to a many base point viewpoint, and tries to involve forms of higher groupoids.

The cited paper contains my views and may not be shared generally!